# Do you convert signed integers to hex before doing an `idiv` in 64-bit Intel CPUs?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, integer-division

Suppose you want to divide -198077031546722079779 by 23 using **gas**. As this dividend is larger than `%rax`, how do you put it in  `%rdx:%rax`? All the books I read on assembly avoid illustrating `idiv` with examples, so I am lost.

Comment: As far as I know gas doesn't do 128 bit arithmetic so you must do it by hand indeed. It does support placing bignums into memory via `.octa` but that requires loading from memory.

Comment: Converting to hex isn't strictly necessary, but that makes it easy to "split" the number into the low part and high part by hand. You could compute those parts in different ways too, up to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put the high bits into `rdx` and the low bits into `rax`, as you probably know.

If you're trying to use the number as a constant in your program, then yes, hex is one possible way to split it up.  I converted it using [calc](https://github.com/lcn2/calc), adding 2^128 to express it as an unsigned two's complement number, then using `printf("%x")` to print it as hex.  The result is `0xfffffffffffffff543210543edc9abdd`.  So we could do

```
movq $0xfffffffffffffff5, %rdx
movq $0x43210543edc9abdd, %rax
```

It would be nice if you could have gas do the arithmetic for you.  It does support arbitrary-precision constants ("bignums") but unfortunately does not let you use them in immediates.  Nor can it do any arithmetic with them, as Jester discovered (per comment below).

However, it does support assembling 128-bit integer data into memory with the `.octa` directive.  So you could do

```
        .section .rodata
number:
        .octa -198077031546722079779
# ...
movq number(%rip), %rax # x86 is little endian, least significant qword is at lower address
movq (number+8)(%rip), %rdx
# ...
```

Note we are using RIP-relative addressing.  If you're in a situation where that isn't appropriate, then just `movq number, %rax ; movq number+8, %rdx`.

If you are receiving the number as input at runtime, then you'll need to implement a decimal-to-binary conversion routine (like `strtol`) but which uses 128-bit arithmetic.  So additions will need an `add/adc` pair, multiplication will need several multiply instructions "longhand" style, etc.

Comment: It supports bignum constants, but I don't think it supports any arithmetic at all, not even for `.octa`. My version certainly can't even add 1, complains about _"left operand is a bignum; integer 0 assumed"_